# CSS select element based on fragment identifier in href attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors, fragment-identifier

I am using the [tabview](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tabview/), which is part of the YUI3 library.

The markup basically looks like this:

```
<div id="demo" class="yui3-tabview-content">
  <ul class="yui3-tabview-list">
    <li class="yui3-tab yui3-widget yui3-tab-selected">
      <a href="#foo" class="yui3-tab-label yui3-tab-content" tabindex="0">foo</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="yui3-tabview-panel">
    <div id="foo" class="yui3-tab-panel yui3-tab-panel-selected">
      <p>
        foo content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A fiddle of the markup: http://jsfiddle.net/zb6su/

Problem: I am writing some javascript code and would like to select a tab given the `tabview-panel`. Let's say I was able to get the id, `foo`, in this case. I would like to select the tab with `a[href=#foo]`.

The problem is that `a[href=#foo]` does not work at all, because `#` is used to select Ids. I have also tried `a[href="#foo"]` to no avail. Is there a css selector to select a link based on a URL fragment in the `href` attribute?

I know that with javascript, I can iterate through all the nodes and check the href attribute, but I would prefer to use a CSS selector where possible.

---

Update: The selector does work. It looks like it's a bug in FireFinder (an extension I am using to test the selectors).

Comment: Works with normal CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/zb6su/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine with the same selector, but using jQuery ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zb6su/1/)).

```
$('a[href="#foo"]').text();
```

Returns "foo". [Same with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/zb6su/3/):

```
a[href="#foo"] {
    color:red;
}
```

---

It seems that the problem was more with F21's FireFinder, not the usage of `a[href="#foo"]`. Case closed.

Comment: Just tried it in YUI and it seems to work too. I was experiementing in FireFinder and it couldn't select it (must be a bug with the extension). I will accept your answer once the wait period is over :)

Comment: You should also update your answer to tell visiting users that this was a bug with something else and not the OP's code.